# Could not find "store" in either the context or props of "Connect(App)".

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I am new to React Js.
Everything works fine until I am trying to do action creator in `ReactJs`.

I know that there are other questions(posts) related to the title,however , I cannot find to solve my problem. Please Help me!

Here is my index.js

```
import 'materialize-css/dist/css/materialize.min.css';
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import { provider } from 'react-redux';
import { createStore, applyMiddleware } from 'redux';
import reduxThunk from 'redux-thunk';

import App from './components/App';
import reducers from './reducers';
import connect from 'react-redux/lib/connect/connect';

// create reducer
const store = createStore(reducers, {}, applyMiddleware(reduxThunk));

// Render the App in the HTML root element which is inside public foler
ReactDOM.render(
    //Provier is to handle redux store actions
    <provider store = { store }><App/></provider> ,
    document.querySelector('#root')
);
```

Here is my App.Js

```
import React,{ Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter, Route} from 'react-router-dom';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import * as actions from '../actions';

import Header from './Header';
const dashboard = () => <h2>DashBoard</h2>
const surveyNew = () => <h2>SurveyNew</h2>
const landing = () => <h2>Landing</h2>

class App extends Component {

    //Call Action Creaters before View is Up
    componentDidMount() {
        this.props.fetchUser();
    }

    render () {
        return (
            <div className="container">
                <BrowserRouter>
                   <div>
                       <Header/>
                       <Route exact path="/" component = {landing} />
                       <Route exact path = "/surveys" component = {dashboard}/>
                       <Route path = "/surveys/new" component = {surveyNew} />
                   </div>
                </BrowserRouter>
            </div>
        );
    }
};

export default connect(null, actions)(App);
```

Any help would be appreciated, Sirs. Thank You

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It is with a capital "p" in "Provider". Try like that:

```
import { Provider } from 'react-redux';
...
<Provider store={store}><App/></Provider> ,
```

Comment: Thanks Man, I totally unaware of that. You've save my day, Man @devserkan